# AWS EMR : setting hadoop credentials provider for S3 Bucket access

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have set up an Spark EMR cluster on AWS (Hadoop 2.8.5, Spark 2.4.4). I have an s3 bucket url and it's access credentials. After setting up the cluster and attaching a notebook, I am able to read the data from the bucket using `spark.read.parquet("s3n://...")` after setting the hadoop configurations using:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId', '...')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey', '...')
```

However I read in numerous documentations that this is not recommended as it stores the keys in the logs. 
So What I am trying is to create a Hadoop credential file in the HDFS file system and then adding an EMR configuration in 'core-site' to provide the credential file path. Following are the steps I followed:
1. Created the EMR Cluster 
2. Using SSH via Putty.exe, I created the hadoop credential file:

```
$ hadoop credential create fs.s3a.access.key -provider jceks://hdfs/<path_to_hdfs_file> -value <aws_access_id>
$ hadoop credential create fs.s3a.secret.key -provider jceks://hdfs/<path_to_hdfs_file> -value <aws_secret_key>
```

3. I added a configuration to the instance profiles from the management console under 'core-site' classification, and provided the path "jceks://hdfs/path_to_hdfs_file" to `spark.hadoop.security.credential.provider.path` and applied configuration to the master and slaves.

**The Issue:** 
Yet, I am not able to access the bucket from the EMR notebook using `spark.read.parquet()`, it throws an Access Denied exception. Am I doing it wrong or is there some intermediate step I am missing here. I do not want to hard code the keys in my EMR notebook. Any help will be highly appreciated. I have been stuck with this issue since a week. 
P.S. The bucket and cluster are in different regions. However, I have also tried the same process by creating the cluster in the same location as the bucket. The issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

- Access to S3 data in EMR should be with with their connector and `s3://` URLs; any other schema references code they don't support.
- You get the access of the IAM role the VM/container was deployed with. Want to access a specific bucket, choose the right role

It's moot, but the s3n connector (obsolete, unsupported) doesn't support JCEKs files

Comment: The IAM role is assigned to only one person in the organization at the moment, and getting the roles for the other accounts will need some time. Without the roles, is there no other way to specify the keys and access the bucket (without hardcoding it in the notebook) ?

Comment: don't know enough about EMR I'm afraid. For ASF-based systems based on Hadoop 3.3+ you can create session/role credentials on the client and submit them with your jobs